# Data not correctly read from hadoop using Filesystem API

Tags: api, hadoop, filesystems

I am trying to read a file from hadoop using filesystem API, I am able to connect hadoop and read the file , however file read contains garbled characters.

Below is the code:

```
public class HdfsToInfaWriter{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //FileUtil futil;
        String hdfsuri=args[0];
        //String src=args[1];
        String localuri=args[1];
        String hdusername=args[2];
        byte[] buffer=new byte[30];
        char c;
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("file:///etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("file:///etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS",hdfsuri);
        conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl",org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
        conf.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
        //futil.copy(srcFS, src, dst, deleteSource, conf)
        try {
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("**************",
                "********************");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME",hdusername);
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","/");
        FSDataInputStream in1 = null;

        try{
                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(hdfsuri),conf);


                Path hdfsreadpath=new Path(hdfsuri);
                CompressionCodecFactory factory = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
                System.out.println("the class for codec is " +factory.getCodec(hdfsreadpath));
                File src1=new File(localuri);
                System.out.println("before copy");
                FileUtil.copy(fs, hdfsreadpath, src1, false, conf);

                }}}
```

When i use hdfs command `hdfs dfs -cat /bigdatahdfs/datamart/trial.txt`, the data in file is a simple text file.

But when I use the command `cat /home/trial1.txt` and copy file to local system, the output is as below:

> ▒▒▒1K▒;▒▒
>   =▒<▒▒▒&▒▒▒

NOTE:- i have tried using IOUtils API also, output is the same.

Comment: How do you know this is actually a text file? The extensions don't really mean anything in Hadoop... In any case, `hdfs dfs -cat` source code is written in Java, so have you tried to copy it exactly? Or otherwise call its main method from your code?

Comment: Did your system admins enable Disk Encryption...? If it is the case you will need extra config properties.

Comment: When I use hdfs dfs -get on file it gets copied as text file.

Comment: I tried checking the encoding format for hdfs file. It comes as null.

Comment: Could you please let me know which config properties checked.